# How to do Pivot (Count (*) ) functionality in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

My Query  is as follows:

I am getting an error "unexpected '*'." at line 6, please let me know , how to rewrite or correct this issue

```
select * from (SELECT gl gl_acc,
                               reg reg,
                               mapp map_name,
                               field as f1
                          FROM gl_acc a
                         WHERE TYPE = 'AGG') PIVOT (count(*)
                                             FOR f1
                                             IN  (
                                                 'JOURN' ,
                                                 'JOU' ,
                                                 'J' ,
                                                 'CASE_' ,
                                                 'JOUR' 
                                                ))as p;
```

Thanks,
Goe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT gl, reg, mapp,
       SUM(CASE WHEN field = 'JOURN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as journ,
       SUM(CASE WHEN field = 'JOU' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as jou,
       SUM(CASE WHEN field = 'J' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as j,
       SUM(CASE WHEN field = 'CASE_' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as case_,
       SUM(CASE WHEN field = 'JOUR' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as jour       
FROM gl_acc a
WHERE TYPE = 'AGG'
GROUP BY gl, reg, mapp;
```

Or more simply using `COUNT_IF()`

```
SELECT gl, reg, mapp,
       COUNT_IF(field = 'JOURN') as journ,
       COUNT_IF(field = 'JOU') as jou,
       COUNT_IF(field = 'J') as j,
       COUNT_IF(field = 'CASE_') as case_,
       COUNT_IF(field = 'JOUR') as jour       
FROM gl_acc a
WHERE TYPE = 'AGG'
GROUP BY gl, reg, mapp;
```

Comment: As an addendum to Gordon's answer, it often is the case that conditional aggregation as used in the answer can outperform the `PIVOT` operator.  In addition, I find Gordon's code to be tidier than the OP.

Comment: If I follow this, I need to change the entire query ,why cant I use count(*) ?

Comment: @asd . . . I don't understand the comment.  You can use `COUNT_IF()`.  But `COUNT(*)` would not create different values for the various columns.

Comment: OK I am from a Oracle world, and there I am used to write count(*) in pivot, I wanted to use same thing in snowflake. Is this not possible?

Answer (score 1):

I would go with conditional aggregation as well. It's easier to read and to maintain.  To get your code to work, you need to specify what exactly you're counting in the `count` function.
You didn't provide a sample, but here is a working code for you to see how that works

```
with cte (num0,num1,str1) as

(select 1,1,'a' union all
 select 2,1,'a')
 
 select *
 from cte
 pivot (count(num1) for str1 in ('a', 'b')) as t(col1, col2, col2)
```

Notice how you can avoid that subquery by using the `as` clause from your pivot to define custom column names.

Comment: I am not counting individual columns , I am doing a count(*)

Comment: @asd please note that if you do `count(f1)` you will be effectively counting the rows -- thus @Phil is giving you here the answer you are looking for